# Crystal report Sum for All

Tags: crystal-reports, report

HI im looking to get a sum of all items not just what is filtered on the report. 
For example
the report is filtered with a date range. I have it currently showing the total footage of items within that date range. But below that I would like to show the total footage of all items including ALL footage not just whats on the report.

Any Ideas on a formula to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subreport for that.

Or change your approach. Let the report retrieve all records and use a conditional total to sum only records within the date range.

Comment: how do I create a sub report?

Comment: That wont work because I need the result on the same report because I then have to calculate the total sum / each total footage

Comment: You can pass information from the subreport to the main report using a shared variable. 
Open online help (F1) and search for 'Shared variables (Crystal syntax)'